# JavaFX Alert - remove title bar icon?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

How do you set that to nothing an alert window title bar icon in JavaFX?

```
 public static void show(String titleString, String messageString, AlertType status, String iconStr)
    {        

        Alert alert = new Alert(status);
        alert.setTitle(titleString);
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText(messageString);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: "that to nothing"?

Comment: @Sedrick title bar icon of an alert window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);`